# Error when using EC2 Instance Connect in the instance was created from Cluster ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I want to connect to EC2 instance that I have created in ECS Cluster with EC2 Instance Connect but it always show same error.

> There was a problem connecting to your instance

> Log in failed. If this instance has just started up, wait a few minutes and try again. Otherwise, ensure the instance is running on an AMI that supports EC2 Instance Connect.

My EC2 instance meet all the requirements to use EC2 Instance Connect (amzn2-ami-ecs-hvm-2.0.20210520-x86_64-ebs) and I have tried with or without SSH key pair assign to instance but all of them show the same error as above.

Anyone know why? Thanks for advance.

Comment: What are security groups on the instance? Also does it have access to the internet?

Comment: @Marcin yes. I have checked it all. I have opened port 22 for SSH and even all type all port in inbound and outbound.

Comment: @Marcin I changed to use user_data to add SSH key so I can access by SSH now. Thanks you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think EBS-optmized AMIs come with EC2 instance connect. You have to [install it](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html#ec2-instance-connect-install) yourself after you establish traditional SSH connection to it, or through a user data:

```
sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect
```

Comment: Thanks you. I will try it. Since I forgot to set SSH key pair for instance so I have to use EC2 instance connect.

Comment: @hoangquyy You have to create new one, or use user_data to install ec2-instance-connect